# Overpass install fails with a broken pipe error

Tags: overpass-api

I've installed a Ubuntu box which will be my one of many overpass api servers.
Basically the installation is good, and I've imported many testing areas including andorra-latest.osm.bz2 and taiwan-latest.osm.bz2. I can't however import china-latest.osm.bz2.

Here is the script I use to import

```
//this one failed
../bin/init_osm3s.sh china-latest.osm.bz2 "db/" "../" --meta=no

//this executes with no problem at all
../bin/init_osm3s.sh andorra-latest.osm.bz2 "db/" "../" --meta=no
```

It takes about 10 seconds to import andorra file with no problem at all. all db files created. But when I tried it with china file, I got this error. I don't have any clue at this moment.

```
../bin/init_osm3s.sh china-latest.osm.bz2  "db/" "../" --meta=no
Reading XML file ... elapsed node 2819628408. ../bin/init_osm3s.sh: line 44: 
12709 Broken pipe             bunzip2 < $PLANET_FILE
 12710 Killed                  | $EXEC_DIR/bin/update_database --db-   
dir=$DB_DIR/ $META $COMPRESSION
```

I downloaded those files using the following links

http://download.geofabrik.de/asia/china-latest.osm.bz2

http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/andorra-latest.osm.bz2

Need your help, please, if you know why or at least theories of how this happened.

P.S. init_osm3s.sh script

```
if [[ -z $3 ]]; then
{
  echo "Usage:  $0  Planet_File  Database_Dir  Executable_Dir  [--meta]"
  echo "        where"
  echo "    Planet_File is the filename and path of the compressed planet     file, including .bz2,"
  echo "    Database_Dir is the directory the database should go into, and"
  echo "    Executable_Dir is the directory that contains the executable     update_database."
  echo "    Add --meta in the end if you want to use meta data."
  exit 0
}; fi

PLANET_FILE="$1"
DB_DIR="$2"
EXEC_DIR="$3"
META="$4"
COMPRESSION="$5"

if [[ ! -s $PLANET_FILE ]]; then
{
  echo "File $PLANET_FILE doesn't exist."
  exit 1
}; fi
mkdir -p "$DB_DIR/"
bunzip2 <$PLANET_FILE | $EXEC_DIR/bin/update_database --db-dir=$DB_DIR/ $META $COMPRESSION
```

Update 1: I was informed that it might be a memory issue, I'll double the ram configuration and try again.

Ram has been increased from 2GB to 6GB. and I'm testing it again.

Update 2: Still doesn't work with 6GB ram but it's improved, now I see a few new lines until it broke again. Increasing the ram to 12GB and testing again.

Update 3: It doesn't work even I increased the ram configuration to 12GB. 12GB has the same result as 6GB was. I gave up. Actually I think it might be the source file, did anyone has tried to import china map ever?

I figured. But who would have expected that importing a 400MB+ file can use more than 10GB of disk space? I increased the disk space to 200GB and Im gonna try again. I Hope this time it works.

Conclusion, if you are going to import china map, make sure you have 15GB+ free disk space and 4GB+ ram with your vm instance. I did it at last.

Also, some of the steps on the wiki telling you how to install overpass api was wrong.
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Installation#Setting_up_the_Web_API

nohup ../src/bin/init_osm3s.sh $PLANET_FILE $DB_DIR $EXEC_DIR &
tail -f nohup.out

this is wrong, $PLANET_FILE was used as a folder and a file in different steps. here $PLANET_FILE is used as a file.

Better to reference another installation guide here to cross reference
http://overpass-api.de/full_installation.html

Comment: Can you post the source of init_osm3s.sh?

Comment: Does dmesg show you more info? Did you monitor your system resources during the import?

Comment: Ok, you guys think it's an out of memory kind of issue, right? I'll try to increase the vm's memory and see if it helps. thanks!

Comment: Disk space requirements will be significantly lower for small extracts in a future release.